# Install of .whl python file not working

Tags: python, pip, pywin

I just installed Python 2.7.12 (32bit) on Windows 10 (64bit) workstation.

Now, I am trying to install pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl from this [Python Library Website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

Attempted to install by

```
pip install pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

And cmd is hanging for past 20 minutes. Please advise.

[image]

#### Update

Solution is install `pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe` from sourceforge.org

Comment: It is installed however, judging from the output. Try CTRL+C, the library should be installed anyway. This could be a bug in pip, or the setup script in pywin.

Comment: @CodingLambdas CTRL+C and such didn't work. And I'm unable to find pywin32 installed on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip likes to check for updates after doing what the command requires: if you are offline or behind a proxy it is going to take a very long time.

Add option `--disable-pip-version-check` to all pip command lines.

Comment: @orenzo-gatti I'm on my home laptop, i.e. no proxy

Comment: To test what pip is really doing, I suggest hitting ctrl-c and looking at the traceback: a typical one I got stops at socket.getfqdn(), indirectly called from pip_version_check().

Comment: When I try `pip --disable-pip-version-check install pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` I get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pywin32==220.1 from file:///C:/Python27/pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl in c:\python27\lib\site-packages` I'm puzzled. Is this normal?

Comment: @Rhonda In that case, your library is already installed. You ran `pip install ...` already, so...

Comment: What's important is the pause after installing or, in this case, skipping the installation. Is it gone?

Comment: @LorenzoGatti I don't think it installed. When I try `import pywin32` I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import pywin32
ImportError: No module named pywin32`

Comment: @LorenzoGatti I just tried installing `pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe` from sourceforge. I restarted python and now can import pythoncom